# adding text below image in a list in HTML

Tags: html, css, list, spacing

Here is what I want to do:
I want to have a few images in a list and I want to have text below each image and very close to each image.

I have tried to use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` but it messes things up.

Here is my list in the html:

```
<div class="verticalStrip">
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="image1.png" alt="im1"/></li>
        <li>text1</li>
        <li><img src="image2.png" alt="im2"/></li>
        <li>text2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

I appreciate any help on this.

**UPDATE1:**
After applying the suggestion in one of the answers as adding this to css:

img {
    display: block;
   }

I got this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any more CSS you're using to compose this?  could you share the relevant snippets?

Comment: Instead of putting it in a seperate `<li>`, can't you just put it inside the same `<li>`, with a `<br>` between the image and the text?

Comment: @Miro no there is nothing else relevant to this.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I tried that, it didn't help. There other thing it might help is to add a `<li>` with empty content, but when I do that it is like adding nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the altered HTML:

```
<div class="verticalStrip">
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="image1.png" alt="im1"/>text1</li>
        <li><img src="image2.png" alt="im2"/>text2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'd suggest the CSS:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yhe4L/).

With regard to the question asked by the OP, in the comments (below):

> is there any way to create some spacing between text1 and image2?

The answer is, of course, 'yes,' simply assign a `margin-bottom` to the `<li>` elements, for example:

```
li {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yhe4L/1/).

Or, if you'd rather, `padding-bottom` could be used instead:

```
li {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yhe4L/2/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but for some reason the text alignment is wrong. I have shown the new alignment in the question for your reference.

Comment: Then you need to show your CSS, because as my demo shows (Safari on iPad Air/iOS 7 and Chrome on Nexus 7/KitKat) this *should* work. Ideally show a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), or similar, to show what's going on.

Comment: also please see that the `text1` is right on top and very close to `image2` I want some space between the two.

Comment: David: is there any way to create some spacing between `text1` and `image2`? thanks for your help.

Comment: I got it to work, just added a `<br>` before `text` and also before `text2`, thanks so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a table? try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="verticalStrip">
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr><td><img src="image1.png" alt="im1"/><br/>text1</td></tr>

        <tr><td><img src="image2.png" alt="im2"/><br/>text2</td> </tr>
    </table>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it has the same issue. How can I add spacing between `text1` and `image2`? Is there a way to add extra space between table elements `<tr>`?

Comment: @TJ1 You could try to make the images div id's and add some CSS.